# Javascript onchange event

Tags: javascript, onchange

Im trying to use Javascript to change the background color of a text input depending upon a value selected in a drop down box.

I want the background color of "businessname" input to be changed to yellow if "Business" is selected from the dropdown.

This is the HTML for the dropdown

```
<select id="type" name="type" onchange="individualOrBusiness()">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="business">Business</option>
    <option value="individual">Individual</option>
</select>
```

The input I wish to change

```
<input type="text" id="businessname" name="businessname">
```

and the Javascript I have tried

```
function individualOrBusiness() {
    var x = document.getElementById("type").value;
    if (x == "Business") {
        document.getElementById("businessname").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}
```

I've tried a few variations on the above however I cant get it to work, if anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: Try change the id of the `select`

Comment: Have you tried using 'selected'? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_selected.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in doubt **look at your data**.

```
alert(x);
```

Your value will never be `"Business"`.

```
<option value="business">Business</option>
               ^^^^^^^^
```

It is `"business"` with a lowercase B.

Comment: aahhhh cant believe it was that, time for some sleep I think. Many thanks Quentin!